# What is the choke on off position in passion xpro?

Tags: motorcycle, choke, hero-honda

Hi am greatly confused with the on/off position of choke in Hero Passion XPro (2014 model).

I am able to set it in three different positions

1. Vertical (the choke switch pointing downwards) (image below)
2. Diagonal
3. Horizontal (pointing towards the fuel switch).

I want to know which of these should i use while riding?

Edit 1 : Image of vertically positioned choke switch : [image]

Comment: You push the lever down to engage the choke half-way and then all the way.  Pushing down means away from the airbox.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Turn the choke ON to start a cold engine.  I cannot see the image, so I do not know if this is vertical or horizontal.  If you can look at the choke blade, the choke is ON when it is blocking the path.  Once it is running, set it to PARTIAL (diagonal) until the engine is warm.  Once the engine has been running a few minutes, set it to OFF.

Choke helps the engine run rich.  This is necessary when the engine is cold.  The engine will start easiest with the choke on.  The engine will run best when warm with the choke off.

Comment: have added the image, can you look into it.Tnx in advance!

Comment: Hard to tell from the picture as I cannot see how the lever's position relates to the choke valve's position.  I am thinking horizontal is ON and vertical is OFF.  The other answer seems to agree.

Answer (score 1):

[Check this out.](http://www.fixya.com/motorcycles/t20875901-kindly_advice_choke_position_passion). It's the same question on another forum.

Based on the markings on other motors I have, that should be closed/on and up would be open/off. Post a picture of the switch in the horizontal position too for more accurate help.

Comment: yeah i had seen it, i was not satisfied with that answer, hence posted here for clarity with image!!